# Calculate rotation angle given Longitude and Latitude in OpenLayers

Tags: vector, maps, openlayers, geospatial, trigonometry

I'm working on an application, where I receive (Latitude, Longitude) from the vehicle's GPS at a rate of 4 times/sec. These coordinates are used to move the location pointer on the map.
I want to rotate the map as the vehicle moves, but I'm not sure how to calculate the rotation angle. As per my research online, I gather that it may be the bearing angle that I would need. So, I have the following questions:

1. Is it really the bearing angle that needs to be calculated for this problem or something else?
2. If it's the bearing angle, should it be just *Math.atan2(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)* where current* is the latitude/longitude at every instant.

I have a running code snippet to showcase the implementation of map rotation in OpenLayers - [MapRotation OL](https://codepen.io/abhipicarro/pen/MWGXEbp?editors=1010)

```
  var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: {
      collapsible: false
    }
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-13617070.95991734, 4951153.5532800285],
    rotation: 0,
    zoom: 10
  })
});

$("#rotator").click(function(){
   console.log("jqyery");
   // get current angular orientation, and rotate by 30 degree i.e PI/6 radians
   map.getView().setRotation(map.getView().getRotation()+ Math.PI/6);
});
```

Comment: If you want bearing/direction of travel, and you don't have it from the device itself, you need to use the current point and the previous point to calculate the bearing/direction of travel.  Given noise, you may also want a larger sample set.

Comment: @geocodezip Let's say I have current point(Lat,Long) and previous 100 points(collected over last25 seconds), how will I calculate the angle by which map needs to be rotated?

Comment: Provide that data

Comment: @geocodezip I wonder why would you need the exact data, shouldn't there be just a mathematical model/formula that could be used? Even if you pick 10 coordinates which are in same line on a street, and the 11th coordinate is after you have made a right turn on the street, that kind of data should work.

Comment: I am more interested in "real" data, I suspect the issues you will have are due to the noise in the data as compared to the rate of travel.  I would suggest looking for duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

The rotation angle/heading angle/bearing angle between two coordinates (src_x, src_y), (dest_x,dest_y) of a regular 2-D map or the Mercator projection EPSG:3857 can be calculated using

`let bearingRad = Math.atan2(dx,dy)` where `dx = dest_x-src_x, dy = dest_y-src_y)`

1. if `bearingRad > 0`, the rotation is clockwise
2. otherwise, the rotation is (bearingRad + Math.PI)*(-1) anti-clockwise.

For rotating the map, the map needs to be rotated by `-1*(bearingRad)` to align with the direction of travel.
A working example of Open Layers map rotation is available here: [Open Layers Map rotation](https://jsfiddle.net/abhishek2k49/Lkdw2yh8/1/#run&togetherjs=8hoDzqSq2c)